# Linking a static library to an Apache module

Tags: c, apache

I am experimenting with Apache module development and therefore I'd like to know how to link a static library to a module (if it is even possible).

Naturally it compiles and installs nicely and Apache fails when the module is loaded. The message is:

`Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_example.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_example.so: undefined symbol: zmq_socket`

The library I want to link is zeromq, I am using the makefile generated by `apxs2`. Here I added `-lzmq`. If I remove zmq related code, the module runs fine.

My platform is Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, gcc4.6.3.

Comment: Why not add the path to the 0MQ library to the `LD_LOAD_LIBRARY` environment variable for the environment Apache runs in?

Answer (score 0):

well, apparently the generated makefile is not a good idea. I replaced the makefile references with basic compilation commands, e.g.:

`apxs2 -c -lzmq mod_example.c`

alk's suggestion in the comment of the question would also work (adding library location to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`), since I was linking another apache-related library (apreq), which linked without any problems.